# Can't populate a table in html using my array in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I can't populate a table in HTML using my array in JS. I'm trying to manipulate the array that I have within the JS to be arranged in the HTML as a table.

Furthermore, I just can't get a hold of this, and it's just the beginning of the project.

Im not sure what else to add so I will rely in lorem ipsum

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

```js
let starWars = [
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "height": "172",
        "mass": "77",
        "hair_color": "blond",
        "skin_color": "fair",
        "eye_color": "blue",
        "gender": "male",
    },
    {
        "name": "C-3PO",
        "height": "167",
        "mass": "75",
        "hair_color": "n/a",
        "skin_color": "gold",
        "eye_color": "yellow",
        "gender": "n/a",
    },
    {
        "name": "R2-D2",
        "height": "96",
        "mass": "32",
        "hair_color": "n/a",
        "skin_color": "white, blue",
        "eye_color": "red",
        "gender": "n/a",
    },
    {
        "name": "Darth Vader",
        "height": "202",
        "mass": "136",
        "hair_color": "none",
        "skin_color": "white",
        "eye_color": "yellow",
        "gender": "male",
    },
    {
        "name": "Leia Organa",
        "height": "150",
        "mass": "49",
        "hair_color": "brown",
        "skin_color": "light",
        "eye_color": "brown",
        "gender": "female",
    },
    {
        "name": "Owen Lars",
        "height": "178",
        "mass": "120",
        "hair_color": "brown, grey",
        "skin_color": "light",
        "eye_color": "blue",
        "gender": "male",
    },
    {
        "name": "Beru Whitesun lars",
        "height": "165",
        "mass": "75",
        "hair_color": "brown",
        "skin_color": "light",
        "eye_color": "blue",
        "gender": "female",
    },
    {
        "name": "R5-D4",
        "height": "97",
        "mass": "32",
        "hair_color": "n/a",
        "skin_color": "white, red",
        "eye_color": "red",
        "gender": "n/a",
    },
    {
        "name": "Biggs Darklighter",
        "height": "183",
        "mass": "84",
        "hair_color": "black",
        "skin_color": "light",
        "eye_color": "brown",
        "gender": "male",
    },
    {
        "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "height": "182",
        "mass": "77",
        "hair_color": "auburn, white",
        "skin_color": "fair",
        "eye_color": "blue-gray",
        "gender": "male",
    }
]
    
    //Popular tabla 
    construirTabla(starWars)

    function construirTabla(data) {
        let table = document.getElementById('starWars')

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].height}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].mass}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].hair_color}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].skin_color}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].eye_color}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].gender}</td>
                    </tr>`
            table.innerHTML + row
        }
    }
```

```css
th { 
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tablas desordenadas y ordenadas </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr  class="bg-info">
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Estatura</th>
            <th>Masa</th>
            <th>Color de pelo</th>
            <th>Color de Piel</th>
            <th>Color Ojos</th>
            <th>Genero</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tbody id="starWars">
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run the JS using Node.js. Node.js is not centred around an HTML document and does not provide a `document` variable.

The script is designed to be executed by a web browser and is loaded into a webpage with a `<script>` element as per the HTML example in your code.

Run your JS by opening that HTML document in a web browser. Do not use Node.js.

Comment: Well I'm using live server, IDK if that is what you mean by running HTML in web browser.

Comment: @EmilioParra — You need to open the HTML document in a web browser. To do that you need to give the web browser the URL to the page. It doesn't matter if that is an HTTP URL hosted on Live Server, a file:/// URL, etc. The error message, however, shows that you are trying to run the JS file in Node.js. You need to not do that.

Comment: You are speaking Chinese now, where do you see the node.js?

Comment: @EmilioParra — All over your error message

Comment: Does it turn into node once I add an array in a js file?

Comment: No. Node.js is a program that you can use to run JavaScript, but not JavaScript that is designed to run in a web browser. See https://nodejs.org/en/ - you are reporting error messages that it outputs (And which browsers do not output).

Comment: Now I understand what you mean lol, I did check it in browser and no list is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just Had to do this, and it worked.

```
> construirTabla(starWars)
    
        function construirTabla(data) {
            let table = document.getElementById('starWars')
    
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let row = `<tr>
                                <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].height}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].mass}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].hair_color}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].skin_color}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].eye_color}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].gender}</td>
                        </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
            }
        }
```